# AppFabric for caching

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services, appfabric

It is possible to use appfabric for non web/asp.net caching ?

say instead of ncache/memcached etc.

Comment: here is a good video which describes the feature comparison of NCache and Appfabric. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CPi1QlskrU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully experimented with Microsoft's project "Velocity" for caching in a non-web application.  Velocity was the code name for what became AppFabric caching.  I have not tried AppFabric caching, because I only have access to Windows XP/Server 2003 systems, and AppFabric requires Vista/7/Server 2008.  Looking at the AppFabric caching documentation, I don't see any reason why it would now only work for web applications.

Comment: do you know if there are any other dependencies/must have's other than vista/win7 ?

Comment: None in particular.  I'm in the queue to get Windows 7 installed on my test PC at work, so I should be trying out AppFabric caching soon.

Answer (score 4):

AppFabric is application-agnostic - there's nothing to prevent you using it in WinForms/WPF/Windows Services applications, in fact I can see that it would lend itself quite well to a Windows Service.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can store any CLR data in appfabric cache, so that is nothing bind the cache service with the web application. 
If you want to compare Appfabric with other cache solution, I think you need consider other points. I think ncache/memcached can also be used in non web/asp.net applications. 
But appfabric cache solution have some other limitations. For example, if you want to use it, you need have Enterprise Edition (or higher) of Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2. You know, enterprise edition is very expensive.